# How to remove lockTable after trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger:

```
Create trigger Update_applicationUpdate_MainTable 
on MainTable 
after update 
as
    Update [SubTable] with(ROWLOCK) 
    set [LatUpdateTime] = SYSDATETIME() 
    where [dbo].[SubTable].[ClientTableId] in (select Id from inserted) 
      and [Table] = '[dbo].[MainTable]';
```

After the start of the transaction:

```
update [dbo].[MainTable]
set [Name] = 'Test1' 
where id = 1
```

Locking the `MainTable` and `SubTable` for another transaction.

How to block only a row?

My second transaction, but it falls pending because the trigger is locking the table:

```
update [dbo].[MainTable]
set [Name] = 'Test1' 
where id = 2
```

I'm using only SQL Server

Comment: Use a `ROWLOCK` hint on `update [dbo].[MainTable]` and you need an index on `MainTable (id) INCLUDE (name)`

Comment: @Charlieface, Do not understand a little bit, do me need to add rowlock in all queries?
why indexing?

Comment: You can't make it lock a single row unless it has a way of finding that row. Normally transactions shouldn't last long enough to cause problematic blocking, but if they do then `ROWLOCK` is sometimes useful. You haven;t really explained why you have a long running transaction anyway

Comment: @Charlieface, because I have a lot of tables (MainTable1, ...) which, when updated, lock the only SubTable table

Comment: Sounds like that might be your real problem, @chilo5432 , you have data have a design that when you update data in a lot of tables, you have to `UPDATE` another one; causing a lot of locks on the other table (especially when the RDBMS doesn't have indexes to help it).

Comment: @Larnu, I need to know when the record was last updated. There is a second table(SubTable) for this. There may be a problem here. But the problem only occurs in the trigger. Everything else works fine

Comment: "*I need to know when the record was last updated"* Why is that information in the table itself?

Comment: @Larnu, on each row? where?

Comment: In a column... Like any other data.

Comment: @Larnu, aaa I can't use this method. because a lot of tables will need to be changed.

Comment: Yep; time to get started!